# Can you use HTML5 local storage to send form contents "later"?

Tags: html, local-storage, form-submit

Let's say someone is writing a reply to an online forum on their iPhone when they lose connection.

Is it possible to use HTML5 local storage to save their submission and post it when they get connection back?

If so, how do I tell if the phone has a connection or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by implementing your custom logic into the app.
To see if a connection is available you could either use `navigator.onLine` flag (but it seems that is not completely reliable):

[Does Safari and/or WebKit implement the equivalent of window.navigator.online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678857/does-safari-and-or-webkit-implement-the-equivalent-of-window-navigator-online)

http://html5demos.com/offline

or try to load content from the internet and see if it's possible or not:

[Checking online status from an iPhone web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492/checking-online-status-from-an-iphone-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use JavaScript to set a variable and make it a string with the content of whatever the user puts in the box? You could use getElementById or similar to get the content from the form.

Then, store it in a "cookie". If you don't know how to do this, here is a quick run down on javascript cookies from w3: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Then on page load you could have it load the cookie and make the value of the form equal to the variable you declared earlier.

Comment: It's a possibility, but that would limit me to 4K.

Comment: i guess that just begs the question, what do you expect your customers/clients to be writing? i think people writing 4k characters on a phone would be a very rare case. if you need more then a different method for sure, but keep in mind this is very simple to set up and may be suitable for your needs (again, how many people will type 4k characters on a phone?)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach (in the light of navigator.onLine behaving inconsistently in different browsers) would be to save whatever the user is typing to localStorage every few seconds or every few keystrokes.

If the page is reloaded again, then you can make sure to first see if there is anything stored in the localStorage key, and if so, then load that into the text box and the user can continue from where he left off.

You can also take a look at the 'going offline with web storage' section of this article http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/taking-your-web-apps-offline-web-storage-appcache-websql/